# Class new Instance in php MVC Structure

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I working with own project using *MVC structure* and autoload class using `PSR-4` using composer. I choose **Php Fastroute** library for my router engine.

My Structure Is:

[image]

index.php

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, true);
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . DS, TRUE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../application/core/Core.php';

// Our framework is now handling itself the request
$app = new Framework\Core();

$response = $app->handle();
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Core;

class Controller
{

    public $templates;

    public function __construct()
    {

        // My Question
        $this->config = new \App\Core\Setting();
        $this->Language = new Language('en');
        $this->Url = new \App\Core\Url(Config::get('URL'),Config::get('URL'));
        $this->templates = new \League\PlatesEngine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));
        $this->Document = new \App\Core\Document();
    }

    public function loadModel($name, $path = null) {

        $path = ($path === null) ? 'Catalog' : $path;

        $path = '\App\\'.$path.'\Model\\'.$name;

        $this->model = new $path;

        return $this->model;

    }

    public function loadController($name) {

        $path = '\App\Catalog\Controller\\'.$name;

        $this->controller = new $path;

        return $this->controller;

    }
}
```

IndexController:

```
namespace App\Catalog\Controller\Home;

class IndexController extends \App\Core\Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $add['power'] = $this->config->get('on');
        $data['title'] = $this->Language->get('text_title');
        $this->templates->addData($data, 'common/header');
        //.... More Code
    }
}
```

In action I put class new instance(library and core class ie: Config or Ducoment or Templates or many more if need ...) in `__construct()` Of Bridge `Controller` and extends `IndexController`. this model work for me But i don't know this method is true Or false?! Actually, I need to load Object (new instance) From Core class to my `IndexController` But I don't know where will it be placed(better and true)?! (in `Base Controller` - In `IndexController` - In `Core.php and require` - In `Index.php`)??

Comment: at least config,url and language could be newd in the index.php and then passed to $app = new Framework\Core($config,$url,$language);

Comment: There will be no right or wrong answer to this question. It's a matter of opinion what would be the best way. There is no such thing as "The PHP MVC structure".

Comment: @jrswgtr: whats your mean:`There is no such thing as "The PHP MVC structure"`

Comment: MVC structure is something that does not exist in PHP itself. People implement it themselves when building frameworks or applications. That means that there is not exactly a wrong or right way to do it. There a better and worse ways, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @jrswgtr: Sure, I add this question for share better idea(better and worse ways).

Comment: SO is meant for questions about concrete problems. For advice and opinion on your code you can better post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give you some ideas how to structure a [MVC 2](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/781074/59565895-13315500-9059-11e9-9815-34ce85ed498a.png) web application in PHP:

Directory structure

- Use the [Standard PHP package skeleton](https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton)

Use PHP (FIG) standards like

- Modern coding style (PSR-1, PSR-2, PSR-12)
- PHPDoc Standard (PSR-5, PSR-19)
- Class Autoloader (PSR-4)
- HTTP request and response (PSR-7)
- HTTP Server Request Handlers, Middleware (PSR-15)
- HTTP Factories (PSR-17)
- Dependency injection container (PSR-11): league/container

Other useful tips and libraries:

- Use a router: I would recommend league/route (based on fastroute)
- Single action controllers ([ADR](https://github.com/pmjones/adr/blob/master/ADR.md))
- Logging (PSR-3): monolog/monolog
- Database Migrations: Phinx
- Date and time handling: Chronos
- Console Commands: Symfony/console
- Unit testing: PHPUnit

To your question:

- Don't use inheritance (extend) anymore (if possible), use composition (dependency injection) instead.
- Use construtor injection
- Don't create the instances yourself, let the dependency injection container (DIC) handle this task.
- Make your classes "final" by default (except Repository classes)
- Your controller should be only handle one thing (SRP). A single action controller would be more SOLID compliant.
- Are you sure that all controller properties must be public?
- The term "Model" sounds like the "Active Record Anti-pattern" to me. Maybe consider "Repositories" as a better solution.